# Can a circulant matrix be unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can a circulant matrix also be unitary? That is, if $C$ is a circulant matrix, is it possible that $C^\dagger C = I$ ?  If this is possible, then how do I construct such matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every circulant matrix can be written as $U^\dagger D U$, where $U = \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i pq}n}\right)_{0 \leq p, q < n}$ is a unitary matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

In fact, this gives a bijection between circulant matrices and diagonal matrices.

Therefore a circulant matrix is unitary if and only if the corresponding diagonal matrix is unitary, i.e. $D = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_0, \dots, \lambda_{n-1})$ with $|\lambda_i| = 1$.

In that case, the circulant matrix $U^\dagger D U$ is unitary. The first row of the matrix is $(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n - 1})$ with $a_p = \sum_{0 \leq q < n} \lambda_q e^{\frac{2\pi i pq}n}$.